# Laravel Backpack - separate from admin and normal user after login redirect path

Tags: laravel-backpack

What I did
after I successful login the admin user, I visit again to /admin/login, it redirect to /,
even after login user access to `/admin/login`, it should be redirect to `/admin`, I do not want to access `RouteServiceProvider::HOME`, how to detect two different user session?

What I expected to happen
I expect to redirect to "home_link" location 'admin/dashboard'

What happened
It redirect to /

What I've already tried to fix it
I install Laravel/Breeze, I can set it from the RouteServiceProvider
public const HOME = '/';

**But it want to separate from admin and normal user, How can I set the it path?**

Backpack, Laravel, PHP, DB version
When I run php artisan backpack:version the output is:

PHP VERSION:
PHP 7.4.12 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2020 18:37:21) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.4.12, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

LARAVEL VERSION:
v8.12.3@6707480c5f0db7aa07537f9ad93255b64b65b85e

BACKPACK VERSION:
4.1.26@ae68ca24844929ac38d2e792197551e823c43570

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As response from:
https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/3353#issuecomment-734454506

under **/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

I added a check for a guard 'backpack', then redirect to admin dashboard.

```
        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                if($guard == 'backpack')
                    return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }
```